# Multiple remote validations ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

```
namespace EmployeeManagement.ViewModels 
{
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Remote(action:"IsEmailInUse" , controller:"Account")]
        [ValidEmailDomain(allowedDomain:"mail.com" , ErrorMessage ="Domain should be mail.com")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name ="Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password",
            ErrorMessage ="Password and confirmation password do not match")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am applying ValidEmailDomain and IsEmailInUse validation to the Email property. I want to club both of these validations as remote. How should I do it?
If remote validation is not possible, how can I put these two validations together

This is the code for custom validation for ValidEmailDomain

```
public class ValidateEmailDomainAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string allowedDomain;

    public ValidEmailDomainAttribute(string allowedDomain )
    {
        this.allowedDomain = allowedDomain;
    }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string[] strings = value.ToString().Split('@');
        return strings[1].ToUpper() == allowedDomain.ToUpper();
    } Vali
}
```

This is the code for remote validation for IsEmailInUse

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get","Post")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IsEmailInUse(string email)
    {
         var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

        if(user == null)
        {
            return Json(true);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json($"Email {email} already in use");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to club both of these validations as remote.

If the Email is already in use,it must have valid domain.Just add the validation to the remote method:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> IsEmailInUse(string email)
{
    var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

    string[] strings = email.ToString().Split('@');
    var flag = strings[1].ToUpper() == "mail.com".ToUpper();

    if (user == null && flag==true)
    {
        return Json(true);
    }
    if(user!=null)
    {
        return Json($"Email {email} already in use");
    }
    else
    {
        return Json($"Email {email} domain is invalid");
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model RegisterViewModel
    <form>
        <input asp-for="Email" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        @*more properties*@
    </form>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```